# how to serialize and deserialize custom object to xml?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I would like to serialize this object
    Dictionary>>
to xml and deserialise again later in my asp.net application. Does someone know how this can be done?

Thanks in advance

M

Comment: What type of object is there in the `Dictionary<>`?

Comment: This has been asked a zillion of times. Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299071/serializing-net-dictionary or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242260/how-to-serialize-deserialize-a-dictionary-variable

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959/net-xml-serialization-gotchas) is an implementation of the dictionary class that can be serialized to xml and back

Answer (score 0):

May be this tutorial helps you. 
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization